# getting interior color of the cell in excel

Tags: c#, excel

I need to highlight the cells with wrong data in excel with golden color which I am able to do. But as soon as the user corrects the data and clicks on validate button the interior color should be revert back to original interior color. This is not happening. Please point out the error. And please suggest exact code because I've tried many thing but nothing has worked so far.

```
private void ValidateButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
      {
          bool LeftUntagged = false;
          Excel.Workbook RawExcel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
          Excel.Worksheet sheet = null;
          Excel.Range matrix = sheet.UsedRange;
          for (int x = 1; x <= matrix.Rows.Count; x++)
          {
              for (int y = 1; y <= matrix.Columns.Count; y++)
              {
                  string CellColor = sheet.Cells[x, y].Interior.Color.ToString();
                  if (sheet.Cells[x, y].Value != null && (Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbGold.Equals(sheet.Cells[x, y].Interior.Color) || Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbWhite.Equals(sheet.Cells[x, y].Interior.Color)))
                  {
                      sheet.Cells[x, y].Interior.Color = Color.Transparent;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieved what I was trying to do. Here is the solution:

```
private void ValidateButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
      {
          bool LeftUntagged = false;
          Excel.Workbook RawExcel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
          Excel.Worksheet sheet = null;
          Excel.Range matrix = sheet.UsedRange;
          for (int x = 1; x <= matrix.Rows.Count; x++)
          {
              for (int y = 1; y <= matrix.Columns.Count; y++)
              {
                  string CellColor = sheet.Cells[x, y].Interior.Color.ToString(); //Here I go double value which is converted to string.
                  if (sheet.Cells[x, y].Value != null && (CellColor == Color.Transparent.ToArgb().ToString() || **CellColor == Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbGold.GetHashCode().ToString()**))
                  {
                      sheet.Cells[x, y].Interior.Color = Color.Transparent;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
```

Comment: I can't see the `.Interior` after `Cell[x, y]`. It says it is not found or if I am missing assembly directive.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sheet.Cells[x, y].Interior.ColorIndex =  -4142;  //xlNone
```

Comment: But how should I compare the colors?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to use the `ColorIndex`.  A full list of values can be found at [Adding Color to Excel 2007 Worksheets by Using the ColorIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296089%28v=office.12%29.aspx#xlDiscoveringColorIndex_ColorIndexProperty).

In the code, just use the index from figure 1 in the link above.

```
// For example
sheet.Cells[x, y].Interior.ColorIndex = 3; // Set to RED
```

If you need to compare colors, you can simply compare the `ColorIndex` value

Answer (score 0):

(too large for a comment)
So you want to colour a cell, based on its contents, compared to some other cell's contents. In order to achieve that, you have created a macro which you need to launch in order to see its results.

Instead of that, I'd advise you to use [conditional formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f). It does exactly what you want and there's no need for launching a macro anymore, it all happens immediately.

Can you give an example of what you call "wrong data", I might try to find the condition, needed for configuring the conditional formatting.